# Spam links are getting through

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, new-users, spam

I was aware that new users were unable to post links.  If this is true, then how is the below getting through?  I've been noticing this particular type of spam more often, perhaps something could be adjusted to stop it from happening?

> [image]

Comment: Here's the question for the 10ks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470514/how-to-read-and-write-a-file-using-javascript

Comment: New users can post links, [just not more than two](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user).

Comment: New users can't post *images*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is by design. New users can post up to two hyperlinks, which is exactly what happened here.

Confirmed via [the privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user):

> New users cannot:
>
> post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile

The best thing to do about spam is flagging it. Moderators squash it pretty quickly and multiple spam flags by uses actually can delete posts without moderator involvement.

If a specific link appears a lot, we can blacklist them as well. Make a meta request or flag for moderator attention in that case.

Comment: And honestly: new users *need* to be able to post links. I find the most well-researched newbie questions are usually the ones that include a link or two (for example to related documentation and/or tutorials that they followed).